# Enhancement point: valid place for insertion?

Tags: abap

We are writing an ABAP parser that is used to parse customer code and SAP standard objects.  Now, I came across a class definition that just consists of an enhancement point

```
CLASS lcl_node_delivery_group DEFINITION INHERITING FROM lcl_node_base.
ENHANCEMENT-POINT /SPE/INB_GR_TN_DLVG_DEF_01 SPOTS /SPE/INB_GR STATIC.
ENDCLASS.
```

I went through the ABAP Keyword Documentation 7.40 and neither the entry for class definition nor for enhancement point state where it is legal to enter one of the latter.  Could you point me to a respective document?

Comment: On stackexchange we generally try to answer questions in the answer itself and not just link to offsite resources.

Comment: I'm perfectly fine of reading the answer here. But in case I've just missed some official document (there should be one), there's no need to copy things verbatim

Comment: I would say, it is nowhere legal, unless You are not a sap-developer, who MUST provide crucial changes in a support package. OR unless you do not work for  a company, which successfully contributed an own module to sap, and also has to deliver crucial changes in an support package. 
You can use those enhancement-points for "plain text modification" of every code. You even can do it Yourself, in SAP standard code. But each release or each code-section affecting support package will usually delete custom-modifications made to sap-standard-coding.

Comment: Well, I don't want to write code with enhancement points. I need to parse ABAP code and want to know in which positions they can appear.

Comment: Ahh. That is another topic. Traversing abap  code  down to enhancement implementations is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The enhancement points can occur in any code where SAP wants to support other developers to implement their own code without changing the original. This technique is mainly used by SAP in their code delivered to customers, and these are explicit enhancement points.

You have to be aware also of implicit enhancements. SAP provides enhancement points without any declaration on several places: entry or exit point of a subroutine, class methods, function modules and so on.

The documentation about SAP enhancement framework:

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp1/helpdata/en/94/9cdc40132a8531e10000000a1550b0/content.htm?frameset=/en/a3/1d40425c459923e10000000a155106/frameset.htm